# How to display disk quota warnings to RemoteApp users

Tags: remoteapp, disk-space-utilization

I'm working with a Server 2008 R2 instance that has had RD Web Access/RemoteApp configured for a handful of applications. One of them allows the user to save, and while saving to the server is permitted, the users have a disk quota.

The trouble I'm running into is that the disk quota warnings are not displayed to the users. Is there a simple way to configure RD Web to allow those notifications to be passed through to the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that there isn't a way of doing what you're asking for 'out of the box' but what I would consider:

1. If the software in question is yours then I would let the software monitor free space available.
2. If not then an overnight powershell script to e-mail those users who are close to their quota.
3. Unless you're saving a lot of data daily, for example that a user might go through 50% of his quote the same day, then this might go down to user education.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'd came to a similar conclusion in my research. Thanks for the suggestions.